# Angular Js location.path working only with refresh button

Tags: angularjs

`appController.js`

```
$scope.showPageHero = $location.path() ;
```

`app.js`

```
  $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        }).
        when('/view', {
            templateUrl: 'view.html',
            controller: 'viewController',
            auth: true
        }).
        when('/details', {
            templateUrl: 'details.html',
            controller: 'detailsController',
            auth: true
        })
```

`index.jsp`

```
<li><a ng-href="#/login" >Login</a></li>
<li><a ng-href="#/view" >view</a></li>
<li><a ng-href="#/details" >Global</a></li>
.
.

<fieldset ng-if="showPageHero == '/view'">
<h1><span>Hi... {{showPageHero}} </span></h1> 
</fieldset>
```

I'm using `$location.path()` to find the current url of the application, its working when i hit the url directly or refresh the page. But it's not working while clicking the same thru the `href` in the webpage. Is there anyway to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: try to put `$scope.showPageHero = $location.path() ;` inside `viewController` because it is the responsible controller for that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
$scope.showPageHero = $location.path();
```

is executed once, when the appController is instantiated, at the very beginning of the application. So it gets the location **at that moment**, and stores it in a variable. The variable never changes after.

So you have two choices:

- subscribe on location change events in order to update this variable every time the location changes
- ask for the current path at each digest loop

The second one is simpler (although a bit less efficient):

```
<fieldset ng-if="showPageHero() == '/view'">
```

and

```
$scope.showPageHero = function() {
    return $location.path();
}
```